# Calling a function on "<Enter>" on a frame causes the frame to flicker when enter function is called

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to change the color of a frame, and it's components, when the user hovers over it. I've done this a million times before with success but something must be different about this one because instead of simply changing the color, the size of the widget increases for a split second whenever the `<Enter>` or `<Leave>` events are called. This results in a flickering effect about the UI.

When I change my changecolor functions to only change the color of the Frame's children, then I have no issue. What causes the Frame itself to flicker in size when the config option is called?

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
import time




class InfoCard(Frame):
'''A class that displays a value and a caption in a aesthetic manner, on a rectangle. 
A command can be passed that is called on click. If the card has an associated command, the card will respond to hover input. '''
    def __init__(self, parent=None, *,  background=None, foreground=None, labelforeground=None, labeltext=None, value=None, command=None):
        self.parent = parent
        self.master = parent
        self.main = self.master
        self.background=background
        self.foreground=foreground
        self.labelforeground=labelforeground
        self.labeltext=labeltext
        self.value=value
        self.command=command


        Frame.__init__(self, parent)


        self.config(bg = self.background, bd=0,  highlightthickness=0, highlightcolor=self.background, highlightbackground=self.background)
        self.frame=Frame(self, bg=self.background, relief=FLAT, bd=0, highlightthickness=0)
        self.frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew', padx=0, pady=0)
        self.valuelabel = Label(self.frame, text = str(self.value), font = ("Segoe UI Light", 28, "normal"), relief=FLAT)
        self.valuelabel.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='ew', padx=5, pady=(5, 0))
        self.valuelabel.config(foreground=self.foreground, background=self.background, bd=0, highlightthickness=0)

        self.textlabel=Label(self.frame, text = str(labeltext), font = ("Segoe UI", 14, "normal"), relief=FLAT)
        self.textlabel.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky='ew', padx=(5, 5), pady=(0, 5))
        self.textlabel.config(foreground=self.labelforeground, background=self.background, bd=0, highlightthickness=0)


        self.frame.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.frame.rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
        self.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.rowconfigure(1, weight=1)

        self.bind('<Button-1>', self.click)
        self.valuelabel.bind('<Button-1>', self.click)
        self.textlabel.bind('<Button-1>', self.click)
        self.bind("<Enter>", self.hover)
        self.bind("<Leave>", self.leave)


        if self.command != None: 
            self.config(cursor="hand2")



    def click(self, event):
        if self.command != None:
            self.command()


    def hover(self, event):
        #print('called hover')
        if self.command != None:
            self.changecolor('light blue')



    def leave(self, event):
        #print('called leave')
        if self.command != None:
            self.leavechangecolor(self.background)

    def changecolor(self, color):
        #print('tried to print')
        #if i leave the next line in the flickering will occur
        self.config(bg=color)
        self.frame.config(bg=color)
        self.textlabel.config(bg=color)
        self.valuelabel.config(bg=color)

    def leavechangecolor(self, color):
        self.config(bg=color)
        self.frame.config(bg=color)
        self.textlabel.config(bg=color)
        self.valuelabel.config(bg=color)



def main(): 

    root = Tk()

    #root.geometry('%dx%d' % (200, 100))



    mycard=InfoCard(root, background='white', foreground='red', labelforeground='blue', labeltext="Total Columns", value=12)
    mycard.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky='ew', padx=50, pady=25)
    yourcard=InfoCard(root, background='white', foreground='red', labelforeground='blue', labeltext="Table Rows", value="5,200")
    yourcard.grid(row=1, column=2, sticky='ew', padx=50, pady=25)
    theircard=InfoCard(root, background='white', foreground='red', labelforeground='blue', labeltext="Columns with Blank Values", value=1, command=printselected)
    theircard.grid(row=1, column=3, sticky='ew', padx=50, pady=25)


    root.columnconfigure(3, weight=1, minsize=300)

    root.update()
    root.mainloop()

def printselected():
    print('the command was called by clicking')

if  __name__ == main(): 
    main()
```

The expected result is that on hover the card item will show as light blue. Instead, it shows as light blue and the card flickers and increases in size briefly, before being redrawn. 
What am I missing?

Comment: This code won't run. It expects a module or object named `colors`

Comment: Bryan, you're right. I removed the reference to the object so it should run with the packages imported at the top.